# spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding doesn't do any overriding

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

A typical scenario. You have your custom spring boot starter. And you need to override specific bean in your starter tests.
After googling and reading some docs you realise that `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding: true` is your only option! (isn't it?)
You have spring boot 3.1
Your app code:

```java
@AutoConfiguration
class MyConfig {
  @Bean
  MyWebClientFilters myWebClientFilters() { ... }

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("myWebClient")
  WebClient myWebClient(WebClient.Builder builder, MyWebClientFilters myWebClientFilters) {
    return builder
      .filter(myWebClientFilters.attachSomeCustomHeader())
      .build()
  }
}
```

You want to test your web client with spring boot environment (so you use `@SpringBootTest`) but with fake filters, so in `test/java/resources/application.yml` you put `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding: true`. I also use wiremock lib to emulate server response, but I omitted related code as it has nothing to do with the subject.

Your test:

```java
@SpringBootTest
class MyTest {
  @TestConfiguration
  class TestConfig { // making this class static doesn't help
    @Bean
    //@Primary adding primary here doesn't help too
    MyWebClientFilters myWebClientFilters() {
      var mock = Mockito.mock(MyWebClientFilters.class)
      // confiure mock
      return mock
    }
  }

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("myWebClient")
  WebClient webClientUnderTest

  @Test
  void test_it() {
    var res = webClientUnderTest.get().retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block()
  }
}
```

It turn's out that the real MyWebClientFilters bean is used in this test.
Why doesn't bean overriding through `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding` works as it should?

Comment: Hm, actually should work. And without `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` do you get `BeanDefinitionOverrideException`?

Comment: @GeorgiiLvov yep, getting exactly this exception without that setting

Comment: I reproduced your case and I also have the same behavior as you. 
But as soon as I change `class TestConfig` to static, then everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have here is `MyWebClientFilters` in `MyConfig` is overriding the one in `TestConfig`.

`spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding` is not really a must in this case.
Since you are using `AutoConfiguration`, you may add [`@ConditionalOnMissingBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html) in `MyConfig`

```java
@AutoConfiguration
class MyConfig {
  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean(MyWebClientFilters.class)
  MyWebClientFilters myWebClientFilters() { ... }
```

So when you have `MyWebClientFilters` from `TestConfig`, the one from `MyConfig` will not be created.